OpenAPI Schema with Springdoc mixing schemas from file with Controller generation
I'am using Springdoc (2.5.0) with Spring Boot 3.3. I'm trying to generate an OpenAPI Spec from MyRestController, which looks like this:
public class MyRestController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<MyMixedResponse> get() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Response(...));
    }
}

My response object looks like this:
@Data
public class MyMixedResponse {
    
    private int id;
    private String attr1;
    private Foo complexFoo;
}

This works so far except Foo. Foo is quite complex (lots of inheritance relationship (up to 6 levels), enumerations, references, arrays).
But with some tools and lots of manual work I was able to cobble the schemas for the Foo object together. These schemas are located in a file foo.json.
Foo is relatively constant and does not change very often, but the rest of the API does change regularly.
Now I would like to load foo.json to a String variable and add it to the generated OpenAPI Spec. So far my approach was to use OpenApiCustomizer but I couldn't figure out how to add a String instead of Schema-Objects.
@Configuration
public class SpringDocConfig {

    String complexFoo = "{\"Foo\": {\n"
     + "\t\t\t\t\"title\": \"A\",\n"
     + "\t\t\t\t\"type\": \"object\",\n"
     + "\t\t\t\t\"properties\": {\n"
     + "...";

    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomizer openApiCustomiser() {
        return openApi -> {
            var schemas = openApi.getComponents().getSchemas();
            schemas.put("complexFoo", complexFoo);
        };
   }
}

Is there a way to mix generated OpenAPI spec with parts of schemas from file?
Thanks and best regards alex
